# A none existing Divbox blocks other Divs

Tags: html, css, position

I am making a Website but some of my divboxes with images in them cant go where I would like them to. I could do it with -50% but its for a project and that would get minus points. Do you guys and girls out there have a idee what would couse my problem?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="staerke">
        <div class="staerke-content">
            <div class="staerke-rotbox">
                <div class="staerke-text">
                <h1  class="staerke-titel">Unsere St&auml;rke</h1>
                <p>A team of specialists</p>
                <p>A flexible structure</p>
                <p>Solution oriented</p>
                <p>Close to you Bern | Biel | Zürich | Luzern</p>
                <p>...</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-2x staerke-iconbox"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="staerke-kleinbild"><img src="img/bild4-klein.png" alt="Schweiz"></div>
            <div class="staerke-hochbild"><img src="img/bild4-hoch.png" alt="Ipad"></div>
            <div class="staerke-grossbild"><img src="img/bild4-gross.png" alt="Arbeit"></div>
            <div class="staerke-spezial"><img src="img/bild4-spezial.png" alt="Glühlampe"></div>
            <div class="staerke-team"><img src="img/bild4-mitarbeiter.png" alt="Mitarbeiter"></div>
    <!--Hintergrund-->

    </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.staerke {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:43.308%; /*  100/2.309 = 43.308...*/
    z-index: -999;
}

.staerke-content {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:pink;
    z-index: -999;
}

.staerke-rotbox {
  background-color: rgb(196, 23, 19); 
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  height: 52.5%;
  width: 27.65%;
  z-index: 999; 
  color: white;
}
.staerke-titel{
  font-size: 53px;
}

.staerke-text{
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  margin-top: 1.75%;
  margin-left: 0.9%;
  position: absolute;
}

.staerke-iconbox {
  background: #EEEBE5;
  color: #81725E;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 12.5%;
  border: none;

  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}

.staerke-kleinbild {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.staerke-hochbild {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: 32%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  z-index: 999;

}

.staerke-grossbild {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: 42%; /*sollte 42%*/
  margin-bottom: -27.8%; /*sollte 3%*/
  z-index: 999;
}

.staerke-spezial {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: 42%; /*sollte 42%*/
  margin-top: 3%; /*sollte 3%*/
  z-index: 999;
}

.staerke-team {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: 54%; /*sollte 54%*/
  margin-top: 3%; /*sollte 3%*/
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Hope you can help me with tips or tricks how you would face the problem. Here a litte help what i wont to achive http://bit.ly/1Jaq9AJ its not the best way to show it but with my little points that all i can do

Answer (score 2):

Does this look like what you're trying to achieve?

```css
.staerke {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.staerke-content {
  background: pink;
}
.staerke-rotbox {
  background-color: rgb(196, 23, 19);
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  color: white;
}
.staerke-titel {
  font-size: 53px;
}
.staerke-text {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  margin-top: 1.75%;
  margin-left: 0.9%;
}
.staerke-liste {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.staerke-liste li {
  clear: left;
}
.staerke-liste img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="staerke">
  <div class="staerke-content">
    <div class="staerke-rotbox">
      <div class="staerke-text">
        <h1 class="staerke-titel">Unsere St&auml;rke</h1>
        <ul class="staerke-liste">
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/">A team of specialists
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/">A flexible structure
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/">Solution oriented
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/">Close to you Bern | Biel | Zürich | Luzern
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/">...
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-2x staerke-iconbox"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first version of my Question wasnt well asked. I added a little example.